# Using GPUImage, how do you apply filter to a paused still camera?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, gpuimage

Is it possible to pause the live feed (i.e. when the user presses a shutter button) and then to apply a filter after it's been paused (i.e. when the user selects some filter) without first saving the image as a `UIImage`?

I've tried pausing the camera feed, and then changing the filter chain (which ends in a `GPUImageView`), however the preview doesn't update.

I'd like the user to preview a bunch of filters first, before actually creating a `UIImage`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone committed an update to do just that.

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/pull/1177